# simplify the creation of a game interface?

Tags: java

I need to develop a small game in java. I thought to do it using awt/swings.

Is there any interface or package that simplifies or provides gaming interface in java?

Comment: Please provide more information. What kind of game, etc.

Comment: Its something similar to snaks and ladder. But the moves may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/):

> PlayN is a cross-platform game abstraction library for writing games that compile to:    Desktop Java, HTML5 Browsers, Android, iOS and Flash.

It comes with a lot of useful stuff focused on gaming, like animations, sound layer, game loop and so on. It is good for you even if you don't want to go to mobile or browsers (in my opinion, you should, but it's up to you).

Answer (score 0):

Every game I have made for Java (not that many) has used AWT/Swings for the interface library. It's easy to use and fast to develop on, so I would recommend it.